# Error with friend non-member function which gives a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, operators, friend, ostream

For this project we are suppose to cover the topic of dynamic memory allocation and deallocation. The functionality of the 'operator<<; is to output(to terminal or file depending on the type of ostream& os object passed as a parameter to it) the MyString data (the C-string representation held within m_buffer). Right after my program prints to the Terminal "Access Successful." I receive a Segmentation fault (core dumped) I am quite sure that it have something to do with the operator << but I do not know how to fix this. Hence, it fails to print "Testing Operator <<()". Any Suggestions? Thank you!

```
//int main
int main(){
std::cout << "Testing operator[]()" << std::endl;
MyString ms_access("Access successful (NOT)");
ms_access[17] = 0;

std::cout << "Testing operator<<()" << std::endl;
cout << ms_access << endl;
}

class MyString{

 public:
MyString();                                            
MyString(const char * str);                              
MyString(const MyString & other_myStr);                  
~MyString();                                              

size_t size() const;                                      
size_t length() const;                                   
const char * c_str() const;                               

bool operator== (const MyString & other_myStr) const;     
MyString & operator= (const MyString & other_myStr);      
MyString operator+ (const MyString & other_myStr) const;  
char & operator[] (size_t index);                         
const char & operator[] (size_t index) const;            

friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const MyString & myStr);   

  private:
   void buffer_deallocate();                                
   void buffer_allocate(size_t size);                        

   char * m_buffer;
   size_t m_size;
};

//definition
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyString& myStr){
//if(os == std::cout){
os << myStr.m_buffer << std::endl;
//}
}

//will allow by-reference accessing of a specific character at index size_tindexwithin the allocated m_bufferchar arrayof a non-constqualified object. 
char& MyString::operator[](size_t index){
size_t counter = 0;
while(counter != index){
    counter++;
}
return m_buffer[counter];
}

//will allow by-reference accessing of a specific character at index size_tindexwithin the allocated m_bufferchar array of a constqualified object.
const char& MyString::operator[](size_t index)const{
size_t counter = 0;
while(counter != index){
    counter++;
}
return m_buffer[counter];
}


void MyString::buffer_deallocate(){
if(m_buffer != NULL){
delete [] m_buffer;
}
}
void MyString::buffer_allocate(size_t size){
if(m_buffer != NULL){
    buffer_deallocate();
}
m_size = size;
m_buffer = new char[m_size];

}
MyString::MyString(){
m_size = 0;
m_buffer = NULL;
 }
MyString::MyString(const char *str){
m_buffer = NULL;
m_size = strlen(str);
buffer_allocate(m_size);
strcpy(m_buffer,str);
}
 MyString::MyString(const MyString &other){
m_buffer = NULL;
m_size = other.m_size;
buffer_allocate(m_size);
strcpy(m_buffer,other.m_buffer);
}

size_t MyString::size()const{
return m_size;
}
size_t MyString::length(){
return strlen(m_buffer)-1;
 }
 const char* MyString::c_str() const {
char *str = NULL;

    str = new char[m_size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m_size;i++){
        str[i] = *(m_buffer+i);
    }
    return str;
    delete [] str;
    str = NULL;

}
bool MyString::operator==(const MyString & other)const{
if(strcmp(m_buffer,other.m_buffer) == 0){
    return true;
}else if (strcmp(m_buffer,other.m_buffer) != 0){
    return false;
}
}
MyString & MyString::operator=(const MyString & str1){
buffer_deallocate();
m_buffer = new char[str1.m_size];
strcpy(m_buffer,str1.m_buffer);

}
MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString & other_myStr)const{
MyString myStr(strcat(m_buffer,other_myStr.m_buffer));
return myStr;

}
```

Comment: Give us the smallest example you can that reproduces the error. We want to be able to run the code ourselves to get the same error to see what's wrong.

Comment: added my operator [], thought it might be useful, since its functionality is used before the testing of operator <<.

Comment: Thanks but we need an actual program that we can copy and paste into our own compilers to get the same error. I can't run your code because it's incomplete.

Comment: Ok I did this, just added the int main and class declaration/definition. The program is longer and I believe this to be the only pertinent data. Let me know!

Comment: Can you provide the full declaration/definition of the `MyString` class?

Comment: done, and thanks for the guidance, i appreciate the help.

Comment: Silly question: why doesn't `operator[]()` just return `m_buffer[index]`? It would be much simpler.

Comment: You don't allocate enough space for you `m_buffer`. `strlen` returns the length of a c-style string excluding the null terminator. Your `strcpy` ends up writing a null terminator one past the end of `m_buffer`.

Comment: Re `operator[]`: you don't need to count from zero to `index` in order to make `counter` the same as `index`, you can assign `counter = index`. In fact, `counter` is also unnecessary.

Comment: Another unnecessary complication: The expected implementation of `c_str` is `{ return m_buffer; }`.